# Complex awk for getting Linux process information

Tags: bash, memory, awk

I would like to be able to use the output of '/bin/ps -C httpd u' (or any process) and use awk to add all %MEM together into a variable.

Example output is:

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root      9636  0.0  1.4 509264 14456 ?        Ss   17:34   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    9639  1.6  7.0 679916 71236 ?        S    17:34   1:13 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    9641  1.6  7.0 680312 71456 ?        S    17:34   1:14 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    9644  1.5  7.0 680320 71356 ?        S    17:34   1:12 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    9645  1.5  7.0 679904 71464 ?        S    17:34   1:08 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    9646  1.7  7.0 680156 71448 ?        S    17:34   1:18 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    9653  1.6  6.9 679640 70572 ?        S    17:34   1:12 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache    9660  1.4  7.0 679972 71240 ?        S    17:34   1:07 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
apache   11248  1.6  7.1 680020 72308 ?        S    17:39   1:10 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
```

I have been using another command to achieve something similar to get the average CPU usage of all cores, so I think it must be possible to do something similar for ps.

```
CpuUtil=`LANG=en_GB.UTF-8 mpstat 1 1 |
         awk '$2 ~ /CPU/ { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i ~ /%idle/) field=i } } $2 ~ /all/ { print 100 - $field}' |
         tail -1`
```

The above outputs average CPU percentage of all cpu's.

So my goal would be to have a variable which outputs total memory percentage used for all instances of a process passed as a parameter.

```
TotalProcMemUsage=`/bin/ps -C httpd u | awk .... `
```

I'm kind of lost after the awk, which I should study, but I don't have the time at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell `ps` to only output the `%MEM` field, which makes it a lot easier to interpret the results. You don't really need `awk` at all:

```
ps -C httpd -o%mem= | paste -sd+ | bc
```

`man ps` describes all the possible keywords you can use in the `-o` option; you can specify more than one, separated by commas. The <kbd>=</kbd> after the keyword indicates that the header should be omitted, which means you don't have to ignore it.

You could feed the result into `awk`, but `paste -sd+ | bc` is a short and simple idiom for adding a list of numbers, one per line.

Comment: Thanks. This seems exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Interpreting your question, you want to add up the values in column 4 of the input, ignoring the first 1 lines of input.  Which can be done:

```
 ps -C httpd |
 awk -v skip=1 -v column=4 'NR<=skip {next} { sum += $column } END { print sum }'
```

Comment: Thanks for this awk version of what I was looking for. Rici's answer might be a better solution however.